# Testing http basic authentication with Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to test the authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic method using Cucumber and Capybara, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Authorization Controller:

```
before_filter :authorize

def show
 flash[:notice] = 'Welcome back!'
end  

private

def authorize
 authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
  username == "admin" && password == "password"
 end
end
```

Cucumber feature:

```
Scenario: Successful login
  When I log in as "admin" with "password"
  Then I should see "Welcome back!"
```

Cucumber step:

```
When /^I log in as "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |username, password|
  visit authorization_path
  authorize username, password
end
```

Error message:

```
expected there to be content "Welcome back!" in "HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I also have tried with the following command, but it doesn't work either:

```
page.driver.browser.basic_authorize(username, password)
```

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work" please? you'll need to explain to us *how* it doesn't work. What error message are you getting at what point? Is there a stacktrace? what does it say in the logs? etc.

Comment: Taryn, the page gives a HTTP Basic: Access denied because the user cannot be authorized. I can login via browser just fine. If I skip the authorization via browser, I receive the same error message that cucumber is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so - at what point is the information failing to get through. Try adding log/puts statements in appropriate locations to probe this.

```
When /^I log in as "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |username, password|
  puts "got into the test-helper with: #{username.inspect} and #{password.inspect}"
  visit authorization_path
  authorize username, password
end


def authorize
  puts "in the authorize method before actually trying to authorize"
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    puts "inside authorize, trying to authenticate against: #{username.inspect} and #{password.inspect}"
    username == "admin" && password == "password"
  end
end
```

If you can see either one in the log/output then at least you'll know that the 
uername/password is getting to that point in the code

Comment: Taryn,  I'm comparing strings inside the controller (username == "admin" && password == "password"). The site will have just one user/admin. Http based authorization doesn't need tables.

Comment: ah yes, sorry I didn't notice that. :P

Comment: Try some puts probing (see updated answer) to at least let us know at what point we're failing to get the right info

Comment: Taryn, I could see the first two puts, but not the last one (puts "inside authorize..."). I have found a few more topics on SO asking the same question and none with a solution. I decided to give up and build a cookie-based authentication, now everything is passing. Many thanks for helping me debugging this problem!

Comment: That means the problem was more fundamental - ie it wasn't even getting to the point where that code was called. So yeah - probably a good call to change tactic - unless you really did want to dig into th whys and wherefores. :P

Answer (score 2):

Use the selenium web driver and visit the website with
page.driver.visit("https://username:password@example.com")

Comment: Good call.

Note that if you're using `Capybara`, that's just a data service layer between `Selenium` and the browser. If something doesn't work in `Capybara`, then the fallback is `page.driver` commands direct from `Selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are showing the welcome message on another page. If this is the case there is a step missing.

```
Scenario: Successful login
  When I log in as "admin" with "password"
  Then I should be on some page
  Then I should see "Welcome back!"
```

Comment: Mahesh, I was changing the controller behavior back and forth trying to solve this problem. I'm editing the question again, excluding the redirect. The problem is that it cannot be redirect or give the flash because the authorization fails.